# Unsubscribable RxJS interval

Tags: express, rxjs

When I run following RxJS snippet in my Express.js server app, the interval observable never stops.

I've tried to run it in a separate file outside the app and it worked just fine. Can anybody explain this to me?

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(tap(() => console.log('foo')))
  .subscribe({next() { console.log('bar')}})
  .unsubscribe()
```

result:

```
foo
foo
foo
...
```

expected result: nothing:)

EDIT: The code above is just meaningless simplification to illustrate the problem. My original code was making periodic requests to a given endpoint. I found out that when I unsubscribe from the observable (after some time), requesting the endpoint never stops.

Comment: Would you like to run the `Interval` only once?

Comment: You subscribe and unsubscribe at once. That means this code should never run. What do you mean with `it worked just fine`? What is fine for you. Please describe. Do have more code example? As i said this code should never run and actually should not receive any results. Strange!

Comment: @Bitcollage Exactly, it should never run. Sorry I thought that it's clear. I've edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: I think I understood you. The interval is running, you make a request and afterwards you unsubscribe and wondering why the request is not canceled, right? Can you show more of your original code? Did you used `rxjs/ajax`?

Comment: @Bitcollage I use `axios` but I believe it's irrelevant. In the example above there is none of that and still it does not work as expected. Sorry I'm a bit in a hurry now, I'll try to replicate the problem in a working fiddle-project in like 2-3 days.

Comment: As i said real code is better or even better a test repo. I would be grateful if I can help you.